# Flask TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.datetime() > str()

Tags: python, datetime

I keep getting this error. I'm trying to set the value of each item in the list equal to **dt** in order to get back since when was it created.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Any help?

```
with open("list.txt", "r", newline="") as tasksFile:
        tasksFileReader= csv.reader(tasksFile)
        dtList = []
        for row in tasksFileReader:
            if len (row[1]) !=0:
                dtList = dtList + [row[1]]
item=dtList[::1]
for item in dtList:
    dt=item
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now > dt:
    diff = now - dt
    dt_is_past = True
else:
    diff = dt - now
    dt_is_past = False

periods = (
    (diff.days / 365, "year", "years"),
    (diff.days / 30, "month", "months"),
    (diff.days / 7, "week", "weeks"),
    (diff.days, "day", "days"),
    (diff.seconds / 3600, "hour", "hours"),
    (diff.seconds / 60, "minute", "minutes"),
    (diff.seconds, "second", "seconds"),
)


for period, singular, plural in periods:

    if period:
        time =  "%d %s %s" % (period, \
            singular if period == 1 else plural, \
            past_ if dt_is_past else future_)
    else:
        time = default 
return render_template('welcome.html', taskList = taskList, time=time,dtList=dtList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You read the date in as string and put it into `dt`. Then you try to compare it with a datetime object, which fails.

Instead you want to parse the `dt` using [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) maybe something like:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The actual format (second parameter) will depend on the format of the date you're trying to parse, refer to the [`strptime()` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the list of parameters.

Comment: Its giving me list index out of range

Comment: Can you provide more information? Where does the error occur?

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm going to change my code its not working this way